# Sqlalchemy - how to define scopefunc in a context where self is not available?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my app, I'm making use of the scopefunc functionality to differentiate my sqlalchemy sessions. It works ok for most of my scenarios, but I'm trying to use this functionality in a wrap function (where self is not available), but my logic breaks, complaining that it cannot find my context var
I'm on Python 3.8

The error i get is :

```
mix-middleware-server    | [bolt.api.grpc.v3.base_request_handler] 2020-10-20 14:19:25,993 DEBUG base_request_handler:26: grpc metadata: key=x-user-id value=1
mix-middleware-server    | [bolt.api.grpc.v3.base_request_handler] 2020-10-20 14:19:25,993 DEBUG base_request_handler:31: oauth_user_id=1
mix-middleware-server    | [root] 2020-10-20 14:19:25,993 ERROR grpc_asyncio:65: <ContextVar name='ctx_var' at 0x7f0283c45b80>
mix-middleware-server    | Traceback (most recent call last):
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/bolt-webserver/bolt/api/grpc/v3/base_request_handler.py", line 74, in wrapped
mix-middleware-server    |     _get_user_from_metadata(handler, context.invocation_metadata())
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/bolt-webserver/bolt/api/grpc/v3/base_request_handler.py", line 32, in _get_user_from_metadata
mix-middleware-server    |     user = handler.db.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 163, in do
mix-middleware-server    |     return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1018, in __call__
mix-middleware-server    |     key = self.scopefunc()
mix-middleware-server    | LookupError: <ContextVar name='ctx_var' at 0x7f0283c45b80>
mix-middleware-server    | 
mix-middleware-server    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
mix-middleware-server    | 
mix-middleware-server    | Traceback (most recent call last):
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/bolt-webserver/bolt/api/grpc/grpc_asyncio.py", line 89, in _call_behavior
mix-middleware-server    |     return await behavior(argument, context), True
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/bolt-webserver/bolt/api/grpc/v3/appconfigs_servicer.py", line 79, in ListAppConfigs
mix-middleware-server    |     return await self.Handler(self, context).ListAppConfigs(payload, context)
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/bolt-webserver/bolt/api/grpc/v3/base_request_handler.py", line 80, in wrapped
mix-middleware-server    |     handler.db.rollback()
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 163, in do
mix-middleware-server    |     return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1018, in __call__
mix-middleware-server    |     key = self.scopefunc()
mix-middleware-server    | LookupError: <ContextVar name='ctx_var' at 0x7f0283c45b80>
```

My code looks like this:

```
@wraps(func)
def wrapped(handler, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        if len(args) < 2:
            raise BadRequestError(f'missing argument when calling: {handler.__name__}.{func.__name__}')
        context = args[1]
        _get_user_from_metadata(handler, context.invocation_metadata())
        _fake_http_request(handler, func)
        handler._prepare(*args)
        return func(handler, *args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as exception:
        # make sure to rollback any open transaction and re-raise error
        handler.db.rollback()
        raise exception

return wrapped


def _get_user_from_metadata(handler, metadata):
""" Get the user from the database using the gRPC metadata.

The user's oauth user id is sent along the gRPC request in a metadata field. By default, the oauth user id
is sent in the x-user-id metadata property.
"""
user = None
for key, value in metadata:
    log.debug(f'grpc metadata: key={key} value={value}')
    if key.lower() != handler.oauth_user_id_header_name.lower():
        continue
    if value is None:
        raise BadRequestError(f'empty http header {handler.oauth_user_id_header_name}.')
    log.debug(f'oauth_user_id={value}')
    user = handler.db.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
    if user is None:
        raise BadRequestError(f'invalid oauth user id {value}.')
    break
if user is None:
    raise BadRequestError(f'missing http header {handler.oauth_user_id_header_name}.')
handler.user = user
```

The db session is passed to the handler like this:

```
class BaseRequestHandler(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self, servicer):
        self.application = servicer.application
        self.ctx_var = contextvars.ContextVar('ctx_var')
        self.ctx_var.set(self)
        self.db = servicer.application.db
```

And it is defined in the service like this:

```
self.ctx_var = contextvars.ContextVar('ctx_var')
    self.ctx_var.set(self)
    self.db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine_from_config({
        'sqlalchemy.url': config.get('sqlalchemy', 'url'),
        'sqlalchemy.echo': config.getboolean('sqlalchemy', 'echo'),
    }, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_size=config.getint('sqlalchemy', 'pool_size')),
        autoflush=config.getboolean('sqlalchemy', 'autoflush'),
        enable_baked_queries=False),
        scopefunc=self.ctx_var.get)
```

Any idea how I can work around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK I've found my problem. It seems that setting the context var at the handler level, is not ok for my scenario. What seems to work is setting the context var value at my application level, like this:

`handler.application.ctx_var.set(handler)`